# using jax.rs.core.MediaType constants

Tags: java, jax-rs

I understand it's a good practice to use the constants defined in `javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType` as in:

```
@GET                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
@Path("/echo/{message}")                                                                                                                                                                                                              
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)                                                                                                                                                                                                       
public String echo(@PathParam("message") String message) {                                                                                                                                                                            
    return message;                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
}
```

Yet, how do I replace the magic string in the following:

```
@Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
```

By creating a static `MediaType` class or instance field using the following constructor perhaps?

```
public MediaType(String type, String subtype, String charset)
```

Comment: Have you thought of adding that annotation at the Class level, so that you do not have to copy this over and over in the same class?

Answer (score 0):

`@Produces.value` accepts strings only, so do not bother with creating new instances of `MediaType`  because you will not be able to use it as an annotation parameter.

At most, define a `String` constant with the value you need and reference it from the `@Produces` and `@Consumes`.